# Recursive triggers on same table not firing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but for some reason, my triggers stop firing after the first time during a recursive update.

Given a table with a parent child relationship:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
(
    [CODE] varchar(30) NOT Null,
    [PARENT] varchar(30) Null,
    [COLUMN1] varchar(30) NOT Null,
    [COLUMN2] varchar(30) NOT Null,
    [UPDATECOUNT] int DEFAULT 0 NOT Null,
    [SQLIDENTITY] uniqueidentifier 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_TRIGGERTEST_SQLIDENTITY] DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PRIK_TRIGGERTEST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [CODE] ASC
    )
    WITH ( IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
);
GO
```

I create 2 triggers, an INSTEAD OF, as I need to do some manipulation of values before it writes the data to the table:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR0_TRIGGERTEST]
ON [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN
    IF ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0
        RETURN;

    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NewCODE varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewPARENT varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewCOLUMN1 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewCOLUMN2 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewUPDATECOUNT int;
    DECLARE @NewSQLIDENTITY uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @OldCODE varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldPARENT varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldCOLUMN1 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldCOLUMN2 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldUPDATECOUNT int;
    DECLARE @OldSQLIDENTITY uniqueidentifier;

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE c_primary CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
            SELECT i.[CODE], i.[PARENT], i.[COLUMN1], i.[COLUMN2], i.[UPDATECOUNT], i.[SQLIDENTITY]
            FROM inserted i;

        OPEN c_primary;

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @NewPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY;
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE c_primary CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
            SELECT i.[CODE], d.[CODE], i.[PARENT], d.[PARENT], i.[COLUMN1], d.[COLUMN1], i.[COLUMN2], d.[COLUMN2], i.[UPDATECOUNT], d.[UPDATECOUNT], i.[SQLIDENTITY], d.[SQLIDENTITY]
            FROM inserted i, deleted d
            WHERE i.[SQLIDENTITY] = d.[SQLIDENTITY];

        OPEN c_primary;

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @OldCODE, @NewPARENT, @OldPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @OldCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @OldCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @OldUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY, @OldSQLIDENTITY;
    END
    ELSE RETURN;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
        BEGIN
            SELECT [Source] = N'PreInsert.1 inserted', * FROM inserted WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
            SELECT [Source] = N'PreInsert.1 values', [@NewCODE] = @NewCODE, [@NewPARENT] = @NewPARENT, [@NewCOLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1, [@NewCOLUMN2] = @NewCOLUMN2, [@NewUPDATECOUNT] = @NewUPDATECOUNT, [@NewSQLIDENTITY] = @NewSQLIDENTITY;

            SET @NewCOLUMN2 = CONCAT( @NewCOLUMN2, N'x' );

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
            ( [CODE], [PARENT], [COLUMN1], [COLUMN2], [SQLIDENTITY] )
            VALUES
            ( @NewCODE, @NewPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @NewSQLIDENTITY );

            SELECT [Source] = N'PreInsert.2 inserted', * FROM inserted WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
            SELECT [Source] = N'PreInsert.2 table', * FROM [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST] WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;

            FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @NewPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY;
        END
        ELSE IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
        BEGIN
            SELECT [Source] = N'PreUpdate.1 inserted', * FROM inserted WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
            SELECT [Source] = N'PreUpdate.1 values', [@NewCODE] = @NewCODE, [@NewPARENT] = @NewPARENT, [@NewCOLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1, [@NewCOLUMN2] = @NewCOLUMN2, [@NewUPDATECOUNT] = @NewUPDATECOUNT, [@NewSQLIDENTITY] = @NewSQLIDENTITY;

            UPDATE [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
            SET [PARENT] = @NewPARENT
            , [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1
            , [COLUMN2] = @NewCOLUMN2
            , [UPDATECOUNT] += 1
            WHERE [SQLIDENTITY] = @NewSQLIDENTITY;

            SELECT [Source] = N'PreUpdate.2 inserted', * FROM inserted WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
            SELECT [Source] = N'PreUpdate.2 table', * FROM [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST] WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
        
            FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @OldCODE, @NewPARENT, @OldPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @OldCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @OldCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @OldUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY, @OldSQLIDENTITY;
        END
    END

    CLOSE c_primary;
    DEALLOCATE c_primary;
END
GO
```

And an AFTER trigger which should recursively update all children of the record being updated:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR1_TRIGGERTEST]
ON [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN
    IF ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0
        RETURN;

    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NewCODE varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewPARENT varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewCOLUMN1 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewCOLUMN2 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @NewUPDATECOUNT int;
    DECLARE @NewSQLIDENTITY uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @OldCODE varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldPARENT varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldCOLUMN1 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldCOLUMN2 varchar(30);
    DECLARE @OldUPDATECOUNT int;
    DECLARE @OldSQLIDENTITY uniqueidentifier;

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE c_primary CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
            SELECT i.[CODE], i.[PARENT], i.[COLUMN1], i.[COLUMN2], i.[UPDATECOUNT], i.[SQLIDENTITY]
            FROM inserted i;

        OPEN c_primary;

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @NewPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY;
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE c_primary CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
            SELECT i.[CODE], d.[CODE], i.[PARENT], d.[PARENT], i.[COLUMN1], d.[COLUMN1], i.[COLUMN2], d.[COLUMN2], i.[UPDATECOUNT], d.[UPDATECOUNT], i.[SQLIDENTITY], d.[SQLIDENTITY]
            FROM inserted i, deleted d
            WHERE i.[SQLIDENTITY] = d.[SQLIDENTITY];

        OPEN c_primary;

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @OldCODE, @NewPARENT, @OldPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @OldCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @OldCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @OldUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY, @OldSQLIDENTITY;
    END
    ELSE RETURN;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
        BEGIN
            SELECT [Source] = N'PostInsert inserted', * FROM inserted WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
            SELECT [Source] = N'PostInsert table', * FROM [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST] WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;

            FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @NewPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY;
        END
        ELSE IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM inserted ) AND EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM deleted )
        BEGIN
            SELECT [Source] = N'PostUpdate inserted', * FROM inserted WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
            SELECT [Source] = N'PostUpdate deleted', * FROM deleted WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;
            SELECT [Source] = N'PostUpdate table', * FROM [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST] WHERE [COLUMN1] = @NewCOLUMN1;

            UPDATE [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
            SET [COLUMN2] = CONCAT( [COLUMN2], N'y' )
            WHERE [PARENT] = @NewCODE;

            FETCH NEXT FROM c_primary INTO @NewCODE, @OldCODE, @NewPARENT, @OldPARENT, @NewCOLUMN1, @OldCOLUMN1, @NewCOLUMN2, @OldCOLUMN2, @NewUPDATECOUNT, @OldUPDATECOUNT, @NewSQLIDENTITY, @OldSQLIDENTITY;
        END
    END

    CLOSE c_primary;
    DEALLOCATE c_primary;
END
GO
```

I insert 5 records with a Parent / Child relationship:

```
SELECT N'Insert statement against TABLE';
GO

DELETE FROM [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST];
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
( [CODE], [PARENT], [COLUMN1], [COLUMN2] )
SELECT N'Level 1', Null, N'Value 1', N'Value 1' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Level 2', N'Level 1', N'Value 2', N'Value 2' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Level 3', N'Level 2', N'Value 3', N'Value 3' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Level 4', N'Level 3', N'Value 4', N'Value 4' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Level 5', N'Level 4', N'Value 5', N'Value 5';

SELECT [Source] = N'Table SELECT', * FROM [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST];
GO
```

And then I try update one of the records, in this case the top one:

```
SELECT N'Update statement against TABLE';
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST]
SET [COLUMN2] = CONCAT( [COLUMN2], N'y' )
WHERE [CODE] = N'Level 1';

SELECT [Source] = N'Table SELECT', * FROM [dbo].[TRIGGERTEST];
GO
```

The triggers for the first update fire just fine, then it tries to update the first child, which then doesn't fire any triggers, but it DOES update the child record.

I'm completely baffled and would appreciate any insights which I'm unaware of.

I have checked my nested triggers and trigger recursion and they're definitely on:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'server trigger recursion', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;
GO

Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'nested triggers' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'server trigger recursion' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
```

Comment: This *immediately* looks like code that should not be in a `TRIGGER`. A `CURSOR` *NEVER* belongs in a `TRIGGER` unless you want to make your DML statements that cause that trigger to run perform like garbage. I suggest taking a much bigger step backwards and instead explain what you are trying to achieve as that trigger, as it currently stands, needs to go. If a set based solution can be implemented, then it should be.

Comment: Yeah, using instead of and after triggers that are recursive suggest you might need to take a step back and reassess your solution.

Comment: @ThomA It's a test to see at a granular level what's going on under the hood of SQL.  Set based on cursor based isn't going to make a difference in why the recursion isn't working correct?

Comment: @siggemannen The recursion is required because the customer wants the children of a record to be updated when they do an update to the record.  While I agree that running a stored proc would be the ideal solution, I don't have the choice in the matter.

Comment: Recursion is never required, it can always be rewritten as a loop

Comment: *"Set based on cursor based isn't going to make a difference in why the recursion isn't working correct?"* I think you missed the point of my comment. The *whole* thing needs a rewrite, and for us to even suggest that, we need to know the fundamentals.

Comment: @siggemannen sorry, I don't think I'm following, what do you mean by doing it as a loop?  Can you give me an example of how a loop would be better than recursion please?

Comment: @ThomA While investigating the requirement of the customer I came across the recursion issue, now I'm trying to understand the WHY.  I'm trying to educate myself to understand what's going on, regardless of any business case.  You're welcome to help me understand the WHY if you can, but I fully understand if that's not something you wish to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `server trigger recursion` configuration option affects server-level triggers only.

Set the `recursive_triggers` database option to ON to ensure your AFTER trigger  fires recursively.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver16#recursive_triggers--on--off-

Comment: Ah, and there's my Homer moment, didn't realise I was checking for the wrong recursion.  Thanks!!